# How better resolve data for controller in Angular + ui-router

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router, iife

I need to resolve data in controller before it's loaded. So I decided to do this in router. But I was wondering how to do this and don't split logic between router and controller. So I've made some research and find out that Todd Motto suggest to create `resolve` function in controller and than use it in router:

main.controller.coffee

```
(->

  Main = (someService) ->
    @data = someService.data

    return

  Main.resolve = () ->
    someService: (someService) ->
      someService.getAll()

  Main
    .$inject = ['someService']

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Main', Main)
)()
```

app.routes.coffee

```
(->

  routes = ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise "/home"

    $stateProvider
      .state 'main',
        url: '/'
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/main.html'
        resolve: Main.resolve
        controller: 'Main'
        controllerAs: 'main'

  routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']

  angular
    .module('app')
    .config(routes)

)()
```

The problem is that when I wrap all modules inside an IIFE (to avoid polluting the global namespace) Main controller is not reachable (undefined) in router. Could somebody advice me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can decouple the resolve function from your controller, make some login inside the resolve and append it to $scope, then it should be reachable from your controller.

Comment: Avraam, I need that resolve from Main controller would be reachable in router like this resolve: Main.resolve

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
(->

      routes = ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise "/home"

        $stateProvider
          .state 'main',
            url: '/'
            templateUr

l: 'app/layout/main.html'
        resolve: {
            main: function() {
                  return Main.resolve;
        },
        controller: 'Main'
        controllerAs: 'main'

  routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']

  angular
    .module('app')
    .config(routes)

)()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Main is <not available> and it's resolve function isn't called when I debug this code in Chrome